# gnuplot: Show values of certain points on axes?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot with a function curve and a few specific points on it. I would like to show the coordinates of those points like this:

[image: plot]

Of course for `x coord` and `y coord` I'd like to have the values of the coordinates of those points. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example plot:

```
$DATA << EOD
1 1
5 5
9 9
EOD

plot sample [t=0:10:1] '+' using 1:1 with lp, \
     $DATA using 1:2:(0):1:(0):2:xtic(1):ytic(2) with boxxyerror
```

[image]